# Using currency symbols and commas in an input of type number

Tags: ios, validation, keyboard, mobile-safari

The best iOS keyboard for entering USD currency values (pictured below) includes numbers 0-9, the decimal symbol, the comma symbol, and the dollar sign. As far as I know, the only way to *get* this keyboard on Mobile Safari is to use `<input type="number">`.

Unfortunately, iOS currently has built-in validation for the `number` input type which screens out commas and dollar symbols. Since this validation "feature" is embedded in the browser and Mobile Safari hasn't yet implemented the `novalidate` directive, there is currently no way to do this validation manually.

Using `<input type="text">` would obviously solve the validation problem, but it also would bring up the regular alpha keyboard, which is not acceptable for my current project (a financial calculator).

I'm on the verge of doing something crazy, like using JavaScript to quickly switch the `type` from `number` to `text` after the `input` receives focus. I'm grasping at straws here. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, JavaScript is the only solution. Here's the simplest way to do it (using jQuery):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('touchstart', function() {
  $(this).attr('type', 'number');
});

$('input[type="text"]').on('keydown blur', function() {
  $(this).attr('type', 'text');
});
```

The idea is simple. The input starts off and ends up with `type="text"`, but it briefly becomes `type="number"` on the `touchstart` event. This causes the correct iOS keyboard to appear. As soon as the user begins to enter any input or leave the field, the input becomes `type="text"` once again, thus circumventing the validation.

There's one downside to this method. When the user returns to an input that has already been filled out, the input will be lost (if it doesn't validate). This means the user won't be able to go back and edit previous fields. In my case, this isn't all that bad because the user may want to use the calculator over and over again with different values, so automatically deleting the input will save them a few steps. However, this may not be ideal in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute `pattern` for your input field as text. This instructs mobile safari to bring up the numeric keyboard. Try something along the lines of:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />
```

Just change your pattern regex to what you want.

Here is [more information on the pattern attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text.attrs.pattern)

**UPDATE**
After reading [Apple's Documentation on managing Text in Webviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW12) it seems like you are out of luck. You will have to do some javascript magic to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the `pattern` attribute. Apple's documentation mentions two patterns specifically, both of which display the numeric keyboard (nearly the same as the telphone keyboard). The numeric keyboard is not an option, since it doesn't even include a decimal (mandatory for a financial calculator) and has no mechanism for displaying more characters. I'm not aware of any other supported patterns (I've tried several but I'm shooting in the dark).

Comment: I've updated the answer. I did try different patterns that should gave what you want but mobile safari just ignores them and presents the regular keyboard.